# Why does winforms CheckBox not meet top of container

Tags: winforms, alignment

I am trying to "pleasantly" align tops of control in a left-to-right flowpanel.

I have a checkbox and several numericUpDowns. BUT the checkbox always has some sort of margin or padding at the top. So, I have to add margn at top of numericUpDown to get them to line up.

This isn't ideal. Why can't I get checkBox to start directly below top of flowpanel, just like numericUpDown does?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public static FlowLayoutPanel ControlPanel;
    public void CreateControls()
    {
        ControlPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        ControlPanel.SuspendLayout();
        ControlPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.LeftToRight;
        ControlPanel.Height = 40;
        ControlPanel.Width = this.flowLayoutPanel1.Width - 10;
        ControlPanel.WrapContents = false;
        ControlPanel.AutoScroll = true;
        ControlPanel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.None;
        ControlPanel.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;

        ControlPanel.Controls.Add(LabelWithText("LB", 60));

        AddNumericUpDown("Ledge", 20, 0, 1m, -500m, 500m);
        AddCheckBox("UseExit", "UseExit", false);
        AddNumericUpDown("WrongLedge", 30, 0, 1m, -500m, 500m);

        AddNumericUpDown("Max", 100000, 0, 100000m, 0m, 1000000m);

        ControlPanel.ResumeLayout();


        this.flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ControlPanel);

    }

    public Label LabelWithText(string text, int width)
    {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.Text = text;
        label.Width = width;
        label.Top = 0;
        return label;
    }

    public void AddCheckBox(string name, string text, bool initialValue)
    {
        CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
        checkBox.Name = name;
        checkBox.Text = text;
        checkBox.Checked = initialValue;
        checkBox.Top = 0;
        checkBox.Margin = new Padding(5,0,0,0);
        checkBox.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
        checkBox.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
        checkBox.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
        ControlPanel.Controls.Add(checkBox);
    }

    public void AddNumericUpDown(string name, double initialValue, int decimalPlaces, decimal increment, decimal minimum, decimal maximum)
    {
        NumericUpDown numericUpDown = new NumericUpDown();
        numericUpDown.DecimalPlaces = decimalPlaces;
        numericUpDown.Increment = increment;
        numericUpDown.Minimum = minimum;
        numericUpDown.Maximum = maximum;
        numericUpDown.Value = (decimal)initialValue;
        numericUpDown.Name = name;
        numericUpDown.Visible = true;
        numericUpDown.Margin = new Padding(2);
        numericUpDown.Top = 0;
        numericUpDown.Width = 80;
        ControlPanel.Controls.Add(LabelWithText(name, 70));
        ControlPanel.Controls.Add(numericUpDown);
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not the tops that are supposed to align.  The baseline of the text is what's supposed to align between various controls.  This is more evident if you use a larger font.

[image]

Comment: If i use all the defaults (i.e don't set any alignments). I still get Checkbox text and tickbox sitting low...

Comment: I have to use: checkBox.Margin = new Padding(0,1,0,0);

Comment: I hear what you're saying about the difference in alignment.  It's challenging because you're trying to do it programmatically.  I wonder if there's a way to make use of [SnapLines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/walkthrough-arranging-controls-on-windows-forms-using-snaplines) when adding controls programmatically.